# Unable to access page after force push

Tags: github-pages

I made a git push --force origin master and after that the github page: ovishake.github.io is throwing me a 404 error. I re-uploaded using drag and drop but still the problem persists. How to solve it?`enter code here`

```
ovishake.github.io ovishake$ git push --force origin master
Enumerating objects: 140, done.
Counting objects: 100% (140/140), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (114/114), done.
Writing objects: 100% (140/140), 27.36 MiB | 1.34 MiB/s, done.
Total 140 (delta 26), reused 135 (delta 23)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (26/26), done.
To https://github.com/Ovishake/ovishake.github.io
 + 41f8cb9...a4682a5 master -> master (forced update)
```

Comment: Did you try reverting to a previous commit?

Comment: Your page is working fine. And why do you use --force on master?